# Add external properties file packaging war Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war

I have .properties file with secured information such as database password ,username and so on, this file locate outside of `src/resources` folder.
Is it possible to add this file to war file on packaging step

Like:

```
mvn clean package -DAddResource=/home/user/secured.properties
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to bake credentials into a build artifact like this. This is exactly why Boot supports both providing a properties file at runtime and using environment variables/system properties/JNDI to supply credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutuions:
1) As I use jenkins , it's possible to use File Plugin , which dynamically add new file to your project
2) Second one , and this is the worst one , you can add spring property location directly to Tomcat in  setenv.sh

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.config.location=/home/site/site/site.properties"
```

The main disadvantage is this file will be the same for all wars you deploy inside Tomcat